# How is a PDF rendered ? Is it in image form or some other way. If it is in image form how is the text selection and copy works then?

Tags: python, pdf, kivy, rendering, kivymd

How is a a PDF rendered in a way where the reader can interact with it (select and copy texts , highlight texts).

Is it in image form or something different.

In any case how does the interactions work

I am trying to build a PDF viewer in Python {Kivy or KivyMD}

Comment: Either you decide to let a PDF library like PyMuPDF render the page for you, and your app then displays the generated image with the cosen GUI manager Kivy - **_OR_** (and I am not really serious now) you read the PDF manual and learn the rendering syntax as you find it in Page `/Contents` sources.

Comment: If I render using PyMuPDF , how can I add effects like  ¹text selection and copying , ²highlighting the text  ³zoom in and out. Etc.

Comment: Youwill use the GUI to show the page image (from its raster format copy. Clever handling of page image with different resolution will allow you to zoom, and to paint rectangles for highlighting, copying etc. Transform such GUI windows rects back to rects in page coordinats to do the actual highlighting, or extracting text from within etc. All actual work with the page is done with the page in the PDF. The GUI's function is that of a visualizer, and you will have to refresh the page image for the GUI display, after each changes you made to the PDF page.